# awk or grep to estimate average

Tags: awk, grep

I would like to average a list of equally named variables, for example:

```
Blue    0.2
Blue    0.3
Blue    0.6
Red     0.4
Red     0.9
Green   0.5
```

And obtain;

```
Blue   0.3666667
Red    0.65
Green  0.5
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
awk '{A[$1]=A[$1]+$2;if(!C[$1]++){i++};B[i]=$1;} END{for(j=1;j<=i;j++){printf("%s %.03f\n",B[j],A[B[j]]/C[B[j]])}}'   Input_file
```

Will add explanation shortly too.

**EDIT1:** Adding non-one liner form of solution too successfully now.

```
awk '{
        A[$1]=A[$1]+$2;
        if(!C[$1]++){
                        i++
                    };
        B[i]=$1;
     }
        END{
                for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
                                        printf("%s %.03f\n",B[j],A[B[j]]/C[B[j]])
                                 }
           }
    '   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ***awk***'s multidimensional array:

```
awk '{ a[$1]["s"]+=$2; a[$1]["c"]++ }
     END{ for(i in a) print i,a[i]["s"]/a[i]["c"] }' OFS='\t' file
```

- `a[$1]["s"]+=$2` - summing up values for the same *colour*
- `a[$1]["c"]++` - count duplicate *colors*

The output:

```
Red     0.65
Blue    0.366667
Green   0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

With awk you can make two arrays, one to keep the sum of the amount for each color and one for the count, then print the average at the end:

```
awk '{ a[$1]+=$2;b[$1]++ } END { for (i in a) print i"\t"a[i]/b[i] }' file
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the feedback :). You are completely right, I have updated my answer.